# Inequality constraints in system of equations with fmincon (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, constraints, system, equation

I need to solve a system of 44 equations with 44 unknowns (x) of the following form

(-1/(1 - x(t))) + (phi(t) * (1/T) * Σ_{h=45}^{60} β^{h-t})) = 0

where phi_t takes value 0 for t <= 25 and value 1 everywhere else, and where T = phi(1) x(1) + phi(2) x(2) + ... + phi(44)x(44).

I have two types of constraints. First, all x must be between 0.1 and 0.5, and T must be below 0.9.

EDIT: The following links are pictures with the full problem and the associated system of equations that represent the solution, Stack Overflow won't let me post pictures. [Maximization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGG6C.jpg) and [system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeX0y.jpg). The constraint basically means that x(t) \in [0.1, 0.5] for all t and phi(25)x(25) + phi(26)x(26) ... + phi(43)x(43) + phi(44)x(44) <= 0.9

I use Matlab's fmincon and the solution it returns fulfils the constraint place on the τ, **but returns a result for T that is well above the value of 0.9** that it is intended to have as a maximum.

I use the following Main file:

```
clear all
clc

% Solve restricted problem

global beta phi w C R D
C = 25;
R = 40;
D = 55;
beta = 0.99;
phi = [0,1];
w = ones(1,R-1);

phiB = phi(1)*ones(1,R-1);
for i=C:R-1
    phiB(i) = phi(2);
end

lb = 0.1*ones(1,R-1); % Lower bound constraint
ub = 0.5*ones(1,R-1); % Lower bound constraint
rng default % reproducible initial point
x0 = 0.01*ones(R-1,1);
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point','Display','off');
sol = fmincon(@(x)0,x0,phiB,0.9,[],[],lb,ub,@fminconstr,opts)
```

Where the *fmincon* function represents the maximization of a constant and hence the only thing that has to be satisfied are the equality and inequality constraints. It calls the function *fminconstr*, of the form

```
function [c,ceq] = fminconstr(x)

    c = []; % nonlinear inequality
    ceq = fbnd(x); % the fsolve objective is fmincon constraints

end
```

where the constraint is the system of equations, defined by the function *fbnd*

```
function F = fbnd(x)

    global R C D
    global beta
    global phi
    global w

    phiB = phi(1)*ones(1,R-1);
    for i=C:R-1
         phiB(i) = phi(2);
     end

    T =  phiB * x;

    F = NaN(1,R-1);
    for i=1:C
        betaM = beta*ones(1,D-R);
        for j = 1:D-R
            betaM(j) = beta^(R+j-i-1);
        end
        F(i) = ((-1/(w(i)-x(i))) + phi(1)*(1/T)*sum(betaM));            
    end
    for i=C-1:R-1
        betaM = beta*ones(1,D-R);
        for j = 1:D-R
            betaM(j) = beta^(R+j-i-1);
        end
        F(i) = ((-1/(w(i)-x(i))) + sum(phi(2)*betaM'*(1/T)));        
    end

end
```

The program returns values for x between 0.1 and 0.5, so these constraints do work. But when computing T as described in the problem (in fmincon notation I'd understand this constraint is Ax <= b), I obtain values for T of around 4.6, well above the value of 0.9 defined by the constraint.

I also tried defining this constraint as c(x) <= 0, modifying the code as

```
 sol = fmincon(@(x)0,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@fminconstr2,opts)
```

where *fminconstr2* is now

```
function [c,ceq] = fminconstr2(x)

    global phi
    global R 
    global C

    c = fbnd2(x); % nonlinear inequality
    ceq = fbnd(x); % the fsolve objective is fmincon constraints

end
```

and *fbnd2* is

```
function T = fbnd2(x)

    global R C
    global phi

    phiB = phi(1)*ones(1,R-1);
    for i=C:R-1
        phiB(i) = phi(2);
    end

    T =  phiB * x - 0.9;

end
```

and obtain the same result with a T of around 4.6.

I want to solve the same system of equations, but I would need to obtain a value of T that is within the constraint that I specify.

Comment: show us a clear mathematical formulation of the equality constraint, not the code only

Comment: EDIT: The following links are pictures with the full problem and the associated system of equations that represent the solution, Stack Overflow won't let me post pictures. [Maximization problem](https://imgur.com/7EAzaFg) and [system of equations](https://imgur.com/lhm7MM2). The constraint basically means that x(t) \in [0.1, 0.5] for all t and phi(25)x(25) + phi(26)x(26) ... + phi(43)x(43) + phi(44)x(44) <= 0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Your Equality Constraint is logically false. If you set `ceq = []` you'll get solution that satisfy only the lb, ub and T<=0.9 Constraints

Comment: You are absolutely right. Yet if I reduce the lower bound and make it, for example, 0.01 (which would result in a T below 0.9 if each x is at the lower bound), I still have this problem in which the T that the program returns keeps being above 0.9. It only gets solved if I set the lower bound at 0.009, but I don't understand why Matlab would be so sensitive to these bounds.

Comment: @ElenaT.Aguilar Your Equality constraint does not hold logically for all x